# ExtJS: Clear panel content before loading

Tags: extjs

i'm trying to load some content to an existing panel with #{component}.load({url:''}); but the panel has already some content, how do i clear the panel content?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the `panel` method `removeAll(...)`.

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Panel',
    id: 'panel',
    layout: 'form',
    items:
    [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Text',
            value: 'Textfield'
        }
    ]
});

panel.removeAll(true);
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: No, it inserts the new content above the current content, i've got two panels inside it

Comment: im actually using Coolite, i'm trying to do this based on what you said

#{panelId].removeAll(true); #{panelId}.load(url:'some_other_page.aspx', method:'POST'});

inside the Handler attribute of a linkbutotn

Comment: sorry, if an external site is added that happens, if added some other page no content is shown, i'll review the container panel or load method to find the issue, thanks!

Comment: @jgemedina: Try posting a working example - this will challenge us to locate and maybe even solve the problem :)

Comment: here's the container panel and its initial components, when loading from javascript with component.load({}) the initial content remails

http://pastebin.com/Vb14mKZD

Comment: I think you should post a *working* example - not just a minor part of the code. Are you sure the `load` part is called *after* the panels has finished loading?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.getCmp('xxxxxxxxxxx').getStore().removeAll();
```

WHERE `XXXXXXXXX` IS YOUR STORE.